# React validate input with regex and useState hook

Tags: reactjs, regex, react-hooks

I'm trying to build a Password validator. My issue is that the boolean `valid` is always false even when the regex is tested to be correct. I am actually using typescript in my app, but I've made a demo here just in JSX:

[https://codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-nash-v6v8n?file=/src/App.js:433-438)

The App.js file looks like this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const App = () => {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');
  const [valid, setValid] = useState(false);
  const isValidPasswordRegex = /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[#$@!%&*?])[A-Za-z\d#$@!%&*?]{12,}$/;
  //const isValidPasswordRegex = /^\d+$/;

  const validatePassword = (value) => {
    if (!isValidPasswordRegex.test(value)) {
      setValid(!valid);
    } else {
      setValid(valid);
    }
    return valid;
  };

  function onChange(e) {
    setInputValue(e.target.value);
    setValid(validatePassword(e.target.value));
  }
  
  return(
    <div>
      <div>Fill the password input and click elsewhere to blur the field</div>
      <input
        className={`${valid ? 'success' : 'error'}`}
        onChange={onChange}
        onBlur={onBlur}
        value={inputValue}
      />
      <div>{valid.toString()}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I've looked ay many similar questions on SO that seem to be using a very similar logic, but I assume that the app is re-rendering and `valid` is being set to false on each render. I thought useState was the correct implementation and binding this to an onChange event would test the input value each time it is changed. I was concerned my regex was not correct so I also tested a simpler condition (which is commented out here) but that is not the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your code.

1.) `validatePassword` uses the `useState`'s setter, but as a value to set it is using the `valid` state (e.g. `setValid(!valid)`). As `useState`'s setter works asynchronously, this will not use the "latest" state. Just use `true` or `false` directly, no reason to use `valid`. That way you're also safe if `valid` is changed somewhere else in the code.

2.) In your `onChange`, you're calling `validatePassword`, which therefore is always setting the value of `valid` to `false` (or `void`, your example at StackOverflow differs from your example of the CodeSandbox), because you're calling `validatePassword` in your `setValid`.

Just call `validatePassword(...)` instead of `setValid(validatePassword(...))`, as `validatePassword` is already calling `setValid`:

```
  function onChange(e) {
    setInputValue(e.target.value);
    setValid(validatePassword(e.target.value));
  }
```

should be

```
  function onChange(e) {
    setInputValue(e.target.value);
    validatePassword(e.target.value);
  }
```

Another option would be to return `true` or `false` from `validatePassword` and don't call `setValid` inside there, but outside with the return value of `validatePassword`.

---

Working CodeSandbox:  https://codesandbox.io/s/patient-worker-7fs84

I don't understand your regex, so I replaced it with a simple "every character is a letter" for demonstration purposes.

Comment: Thank you. I'd figured out the `onChange` event should be `validatePassword(e.target.value);` but returning valid was driving me around the bend. I am not entering a different world of regex hell. Thank you

Comment: Now entering!  Sorry